# Custom class hierarchy to consume XML with unknown number of (name, value) elements

Tags: vb.net, xml-parsing

Im trying to define an array of structure within another structure but having challenges.
Basically im supposed to consume an xml node like the one below:

```
<additionalData> 
  <nameValuePair> 
    <name>amount</name> 
    <value>10</value> 
  </nameValuePair> 
  <nameValuePair> 
    <name>billerId</name> 
    <value>4665890107880063161</value> 
  </nameValuePair> 
  <nameValuePair> 
    <name>billNumber</name> 
    <value>12434829</value> 
  </nameValuePair> 
</additionalData>
```

I need to define nameValuePair as a structure array within the parent structure called additionalData

Comment: Use List(Of nameValuePair), not an array.  A List can contain any number of items.

Answer (score 1):

The data structure which contains KeyValue-Pairs is a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). You can use it if you don't need a specific order

```
Dim additionalData As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
additionalData.Add("myname", "myvalue")
```

If your items are in specific order you can use `List`

```
Dim additionalData As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))()

Dim additionalDataItem As New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("myname", "myvalue")
additionalData.Add(additionalDataItem)
```

**EDIT:**

```
   struct Transaction
   {
      public Dictionary<string, string> additionalData;
   }

Transaction transaction;
transaction.additionalData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

transaction.additionalData.Add("amount", "10");
```

Comment: thanks for the response... I had declared nameValuePair as a structure called mynameValuePair with name and value and wanted to call it in another structure additionalData which is again called in another structure called transaction

Comment: @mooker please format and post this code as a part of your question

Comment: I made a mistake, im actually supposed to consume the XML into my API. The problem is with my current implementation additionalData receives nothing upon invoking the API

Comment: @mooker: Please update your question accordingly. It still says `generate an xml node`, which is the opposite of what you just said.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code, here `lst` is probably the structure you are looking for:

```
Dim xml As XElement = <additionalData>
                        <nameValuePair>
                          <name>amount</name>
                          <value>10</value>
                        </nameValuePair>
                        <nameValuePair>
                          <name>billerId</name>
                          <value>4665890107880063161</value>
                        </nameValuePair>
                        <nameValuePair>
                          <name>billNumber</name>
                          <value>12434829</value>
                        </nameValuePair>
                      </additionalData>

Dim lst As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
For Each nameValuePair As XElement In xml.Elements
  Dim name As String = nameValuePair.<name>.Value
  Dim value As String = nameValuePair.<value>.Value
  lst.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(name, value))
Next
```

You can replace KeyValuePair with another class of your own, or even the whole generic List with something more sophisticated. The way how you consume an XML file will most likely stay the same.

This is the contents of `lst` after executing the above code (debugger view).

[image]

**EDIT** - If you define some custom classes:

```
Class AdditionalData : Inherits List(Of NameValuePair)
  Sub New(xml As XElement)
    For Each nameValuePair As XElement In xml.Elements
      Dim name As String = nameValuePair.<name>.Value
      Dim value As String = nameValuePair.<value>.Value
      Me.Add(New NameValuePair(name, value))
    Next
  End Sub
End Class

Class NameValuePair
  Public ReadOnly Name As String
  Public ReadOnly Value As String
  Sub New(name As String, value As String)
    Me.Name = name
    Me.Value = value
  End Sub
End Class
```

You can change the above code to this:

```
Dim lst As New AdditionalData(xml) 'xml is inline XML file declared above
```

Or in your case it would probably be:

```
Dim lst As New AdditionalData(XDocument.Load("path_to_xml").Root)
```

I intentionally left it to accept XElement, this way you can pass either an inline XML or a parsed XML (from stream or otherwise) or load from disk. You can even give it a subset of an XML file, if it's a complex structure and `additionalData` is part of it.

Comment: thanks for the snippet, however in your example you have declared and assigned the variable xml then  looped to extract the values. my challenge is implementing a class that expects such an xml. think of it in terms of implementing an API that expects a call with that xml layout.

Comment: @mooker: So what's the problem? Create a constructor in AdditionalData that expects your XML file as XDocument or XElement. Then feed with XDocument.Parse or XDocument.Load, and if accepting XElement, pass XDocument.Root. Logic will be the same. I showed example with inline XML, because you can copy it to your empty project and play with it there. This is what is called a *reduced test case*.

Comment: Ive implemented the above suggestion (custom class) but now it complains of "mynameValuePair cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor" and when i add a parameterless constructor it throws another exception "Count = (Count) threw an exception of type System.TypeLoadException."

Comment: @mooker: Are you trying to **write** this custom class to an XML file? For **reading**, just pass an XML document like I suggested above. You can think of it as a custom serialization code. In any case, I can have a look at your code - please post below in your answer.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion solved my problem after a few modifications